# What is an alternative word to "journey" for a shorter travelling time?

Tags: word-choice

I want to ask someone that how was his journey  but the drive is too short to be considered as journey. What other word I can use instead of it?

Comment: Thesaurus entry for *journey*: http://thesaurus.com/browse/journey

Comment: A common way to ask would be to name the mode of transportation .. "how was your walk?" "how was your flight?" "how was your bus-ride?" "how was the drive" -  the suggestion 'trip' below certainly a good answer akin to journey's broadness, but naming the manner of locomotion has a certain extra something to it ...but I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Trip*, usually.

Occasionally I've heard "short hop", but that generally refers to short airplane trips (which are no longer very short at all, thanks to the security lines).

Answer (score 6):

An alternative answer could be a **jaunt** - Noun: A short excursion or journey for pleasure.

Usage - "The store is just a quick jaunt down the road."

Answer (score 4):

You could ask

> How was your trip?

However, if the person is simply arriving at your location from some other place, and drove to your location, you could also ask:

> How was your drive?

Hope this helps.